# How to run a custom aggregation on a queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model called `LeaveEntry`:

```
class LeaveEntry(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        limit_choices_to={'is_active': True},
        unique_for_date='date'
    )
    half_day = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I get a set of LeaveEntries with the filter:

```
LeaveEntry.objects.filter(
    leave_request=self.unapproved_leave
).count()
```

I would like to get an aggregation called total days, so where a LeaveEntry has `half_day=True` then it is half a day so `0.5`.

What I was thinking based on the [django aggregations docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/) was annotating the days like this:

```
days = LeaveEntry.objects.annotate(days=<If this half_day is True: 0.5 else 1>)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use django's conditional expressions [`Case` and `When`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) (only for django 1.8+):

Keeping [the order of `filter()` and `annotate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses) in wind you can count the the number of days left for unapproved leaves like so:

```
from django.db.models import FloatField, Case, When
# ...
LeaveEntry.objects.filter(
    leave_request=self.unapproved_leave  # not sure what self relates to
    ).annotate(
        days=Count(Case(
            When(half_day=True, then=0.5),
            When(half_day=False, then=1),
            output_field=FloatField()
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks jojo, I edited the answer slightly. Now can I read a function on the queryset so instead of `.count()` I can do `.count_days()`?

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, you would like to perform the count on the queryset of LeaveEntry with the`leave_request=self.upapproved_leave` filter?

Comment: Yeah so `LeaveEntry.objects.filter(leave_request=self.unapproved_leave).custom_day_count()`?

Comment: Hm, I'm not familiar with defining custom `count()`'s. I updated my answer to include the filter on `unapproved_leave`s. Note that `annotate` is not a closing statement, so for example `.values('days')` should work just fine. I'm not sure if this is really what you are looking for.

Comment: @surfer190 did you have any luck with that?

Comment: I used [custom queryset methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/managers/#calling-custom-queryset-methods-from-the-manager)